# Odoo: Change One2many "add new line" behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I have made a custom model and for a user to make an order they have to 1) click on add new line, 2) either select one of the products from the list or 3) click on search more, and search for the desired product. 
As shown above these are a lot of steps given they can be adding more than 50 items during 1 order 
I want to change the behavior of the hyperlink "add new line" of a one2many field, to directly open the full view of the products (as if a user clicked search more) then return the result back to the one2many field.

[image]